# Linearly Spaced Array in C

Tags: c, pointers, linspace

I'm trying to replicate the linspace functions from Matlab and numpy (python) in C however, I keep getting the warning about **dereferencing NULL pointer**.

I'm very much a novice at C and having only worked in Matlab, python and lua before, pointers are quite something to try and wrap my head around!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

 double* linspace(double init, double fin, int N) {
     double *x;
     int i = 0;
     double step = (fin - init) / (double)N;
     x = (double*)calloc(N, sizeof(double));

     x[i] = init; /*<=== Line 14*/

     for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
         x[i] = x[i - 1] + step;
     }
     x[N - 1] = fin;
     return x;
}

int main() {
    double *x_array = linspace(0, 10, 1000);

    printf(&x_array);

    free(x_array);
    return 0;
}
```

And I get the exact warning:

```
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'x'. Line 14
```

Obviously I'm sure its just a rookie mistake but I'm unsure of how to sort it!

Thanks.

Comment: You can't call `printf` like that. C doesn't have high-level print statements like Python. If you want to print the array, use a loop. Or craeet an array-printing function with a loop. (But the compiler really should have warned you. The first argument to `printf` is nearly always a string literal.)

Comment: Well if the problem is indeed with this line `x[i] = init;` then `calloc` failed somewhy and returned NULL. With fixed printing there is no error in your code here at least https://onlinegdb.com/r1wCaAor8.

Comment: Is this a compiler warning or a runtime error?  I can see the compiler warning you about dereferencing a pointer which *might* be NULL (if `calloc` failed), and it would certainly be good practice to check the pointer before proceeding.  That said, if your system actually can't allocate 8000 bytes at runtime, you have bigger problems.

Comment: I suppose the printf isn't particularly important, just more to show me that it works! So I'm sure I can rework that to print the array in a proper manner, thank you. It appears its just a compiler warning, so I'll definitely make it check the pointer first. I think the main issue is with the improper use of printf as it now prints a sequence of random symbols. Thank you all

Comment: But as it stands, the printf will at least print garbage, and probably crash.

Comment: As a compilation error, that doesn't make much sense.  In theory, `calloc()` could fail at runtime, but the compiler can't diagnose that as an unconditional error. You should check the return value, but the compiler should not complain.

Comment: It was a compilation warning not an error, obviously big distinctions between the two! Thank you all for your insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following message:

```
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'x'. Line 14
```

is not a runtime error.  It is a very badly worded warning issued by the Microsoft C++ compiler (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=vs-2019) about the ***possibility*** that you might be dereferencing a pointer which ***might*** be `NULL` at runtime.

Your pointer will be `NULL` if `calloc()` fails to allocate memory, an eventuality that you probably do not need to worry about, but to keep the compiler happy and prevent the warning, you might want to `ASSERT()` that the pointer is not `NULL` before proceeding to dereference the pointer.

And if you want to write perfectly robust code, then you need to add code which makes your function gracefully fail if `calloc()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: “an eventuality that you probably do not need to worry about” — you absolutely *should*. Allocations in C can fail, handle this failure. You can’t do much *about* it, but you should fail with a clear error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, sure, and I think it may also happen if you have another bug which asks for zero bytes to be allocated.  That's why I added the last statement about perfectly robust code.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your step calculation. It should be:

```
double step = (fin - init) / (double)N-1;
```

For very large arrays, it can be X2 faster if you use the following:

```
double* linspace(double x1, double x2, int n) {

 double *x = calloc(n, sizeof(double));

 double step = (x2 - x1) / (double)(n - 1);

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     x[i] = x1 + ((double)i * step);
 }
 
return x;
}
```